# Upgrade 16.04 -> 18.04 breaks booting

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

I have upgraded 16.04 to 18.04 by following https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver

When booting I get:

[image]

After the timeout the system stops with a black screen after a few minutes.

How can I make the system boot normally?

Comment: That's a lot of fsck output. Why was your filesystem broken?

Comment: I haven't experienced this myself (fingers crossed) but have you tried booting **Advanced Options** and selecting "Recovery" option?

Comment: @user535733 No broken file system.

Answer (score 0):

The device causing the problem is probably the swap partition. Check by opening `/etc/fstab` (with your favourite editor) and compare UUIDs.

To confirm, invoke your favourite editor thus:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

- Comment the swap partition entry by placing a `#` at the beginning of the line.  -
- Reboot.
- If it boots OK, it is recommended that the swap partition is recreated, as in the post below:

[A start job is running for dev-disk-by x2duuid-ad0b043b\x2d404c... .device (7s / 1min 30s)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956042/a-start-job-is-running-for-dev-disk-by-x2duuid-ad0b043b-x2d404c-device-7s)

Note: I run sparkylinux without a swap partition without any problems, but maybe that's because I never get close to using all of the RAM (8gb).